# Custom Execution Function in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

I am trying to write a simple custom function extension for WS02 (4.2.0). My function basically takes in a String and returns the upper case. This is meant to be a first step POC for a more advanced custom function.

I implemented a class that extended the org.wso2.siddhi.core.executor.function.FunctionExecutor class, and created a ams.siddhiext file. I then packaged the class and the siddhiext in a JAR file using the maven-bundle plugin.

My function class looks like this

```
public class AnomalyDetector extends FunctionExecutor {

private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AnomalyDetector
        .class);

@Override
protected void init(ExpressionExecutor[] expressionExecutors, ExecutionPlanContext executionPlanContext) {
    LOG.info("In AD:init()");
}

@Override
protected Object execute(Object[] objects) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Object execute(Object o) {
    LOG.info("In AD:process(" + o.toString() + ")");
    String eventData = (String) o;
    LOG.info("Event data : " + eventData);
    if (eventData != null) {
        return eventData.toUpperCase();
    } else {
        return "Null event data";
    }
}

@Override
public void start() {
    LOG.info("In AD:start()");
}

@Override
public void stop() {
}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> currentState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Map<String, Object> map) {

}

@Override
public Attribute.Type getReturnType() {
    return Attribute.Type.STRING;
}
```

}

I then put the jar in the /repository/components/lib/ since /repository/components/dropins/ did not pick it up.

I have 2 issues that are blocking me currently.

1. I wanted to write a simple execution plan that takes a value from an input stream (String), invoke my custom function and write the output to an export stream.

@Plan:name('AMSExecutionPlan')

@Import('AMSStream:1.0.0')
define stream amsStream (metrics_json string);

@Export('AnomalyStream:1.0.0')
define stream anomalyStream (anomaly string);

from amsStream
select ams:findAnomaly(metrics_json) as anomaly
insert into anomalyStream

I get the following validation error. 
[image]

What could be wrong with my execution plan?

2. Whenever I change my custom function class, rebuild the jar and replace it in the wso2 classpath, and then restart ws02, I dont see the changes reflected in ws02. The log lines that I print out in my custom function class reflect an older version of the code. What should I do to make changes to my Custom function class on a live ws02 instance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you bundle the jar as an OSGI bundle and try? There can be a issue when converting your jar to an OSGI bundle.

Answer (score 0):

1. Validation error you have pointed suggest that your extension is not returning the return type properly. But I can see you have implemented getReturnType() correctly. So may be your source and actual running code might not be synced up due to issue 2. So let's address that first.
2. In WSO2 servers lib folder is used to add non-OSGi dependencies and dropins for OSGi dependencies. Fact that it works in lib and not in dropins suggest that your jar is not packed as a bundle. To achieve that please follow below pom file from String extension. There are two things to note.

[1] Usage of bundle packaging

[2] Usage of bundle plugin

Update your pom referencing this and then you will be able to add your bundle to dropins directly. Also this is the reason why your changes are not reflected. When you add your jar to lib server will internally convert it to an OSGi bundle and add to dropins. Now when you update the jar in lib again the one in dropins will not get updated. It will be the old bundle. Hence changes are not reflected. This issue will also go away when you update the pom and build the bundle correctly.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/v3.1.0/modules/siddhi-extensions/string/pom.xml#L29

[2] https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/v3.1.0/modules/siddhi-extensions/string/pom.xml#L57

Hope this helps!!